# What is the name of the method to find index from array, in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I have a following method to find index of a book object which have a book name:

```
+(NSInteger)indexXXX:(NSString *)bookName XXX:(NSArray *)books
{
  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < books.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *book = [books objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[book objectForKey:@"bookName"] isEqualToString:bookName]) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

But I don't know what name should I use for this method.
Could you tell me some method names commonly used for this kind of method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually we just name methods after what they do, so something like `indexOfObjectWithName: inArray:` would work.

To carry on past answering this question, the method can be made much simpler:

```
{
    NSArray *names = [books valueForKey: @"bookName"];
    return [names indexOfObject: bookName];
}
```